# Laravel 5.1 and PushBullet lahaxearnaud plugin

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, guzzle, pushbullet

I'm trying to send notifications via PushBullet to my mobile phone using the [lahaxearnaud/laravel-pushbullet](https://github.com/lahaxearnaud/laravel-pushbullet) plugin. Only one problem, I installed it correctly and I'm still getting this error: `Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php on line 87 and defined`.

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace RPR\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Mail;
use Validator;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PushBullet;
use RPR\User;
use RPR\News;
use RPR\Sponsors;
use RPR\Partners;
use RPR\Events;
use RPR\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * PostContact
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function PostContact(Request $request)
    {
        $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'U moet een naam opgeven.',
            'name.min' => 'Uw naam moet minstens :min tekens bevatten.',
            'email.required' => 'U moet een e-mail adres opgeven.',
            'email.min' => 'Uw e-mail adres moet minstens :min tekens bevatten.',
            'email.email' => 'Uw e-mail adres moet geldig zijn.',
            'subject.required' => 'U moet een onderwerp opgeven.',
            'subject.min' => 'Uw onderwerp moet minstens :min tekens bevatten.',
            'message.required' => 'U moet een bericht opgeven.',
            'message.min' => 'Uw bericht moet minstens :min tekens bevatten.'
        ];

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|min:3|email',
            'subject' => 'required|min:3',
            'message' => 'required|min:3'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        DB::table('contact')->insert([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'message' => $request->get('message'),
            'ip' => $request->ip(),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

        PushBullet::all()->note('Belangrijk', 'Er is een nieuw contact bericht.');

        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Uw bericht is succesvol verzonden!');
        return Redirect::back();
    }

}
```

The main issue is the `PushBullet::all()->note('Belangrijk', 'Er is een nieuw contact bericht.');` wich does the request. After That is fired, I got the issue. Anyone an idea?

Kindest regards,

Robin